# How to add syntax highlighting to <marked-element>?

Tags: polymer, syntax-highlighting, polymer-1.0, web-component, custom-element

I've been trying to add syntax highlighting to [<marked-element>](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/marked-element) using [<prism-highlighter>](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/prism-element), but I am at a complete loss on how to get this to work.

When reading the documentation for <prism-highlighter>, it states "This flow is supported by <marked-element>", but isn't clear on how to use them together.

When looking into the [<prism-highlighter> source on the GitHub](https://github.com/PolymerElements/prism-element), the only demo given is for when using it alone, and using it this way would miss all the benefit of <marked-element>.

I could access the content with <marked-element>.markdown, but I can't figure out how I would process it and send it back, and every attempt to do so failed.

How do I used <marked-element> for the markdown, and also add syntax highlighting?

Or maybe change the [iron-demo-helpers' <demo-snippet>](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-demo-helpers) so that I get the nice layout with the copy button, but for different languages like bash and python scripts. (Which are both supported according to the [supported languages on the PrismJS website](http://prismjs.com/#languages-list).)

Edit: It turns out that it wasn't how I was doing it that was wrong, but that the language I was using wasn't supported by default. Posted solution as answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the `<marked-element>` with your code after the `<prism-highlighter>` tag, just as below:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/marked-element/marked-element.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/prism-element/prism-highlighter.html">
</head>
<body>
    <prism-highlighter></prism-highlighter>
    <marked-element>
        <script type="text/markdown">
            ```html
            <div>yes</div>
            <i>
                console.log( "no log" )
            </i>
            ```
        </script>
    </marked-element>
</body>
</html>
````

The highlighter will detect and style the elements inside the `<marked-element>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it showed me that it wasn't HOW I was doing it that was wrong, but that the language I was trying to use wasn't included in either the prism-highlighter or the compiled prism.js file. I will mark your answer as correct since it does answer the question, and then I'll post the solution to my problem as well, but first can you please edit it so that instead of having prism-highlighter surrounding marked-element, it's above it as recommended, and clarify what the zzmarkdown is meant to do, or remove it?

Answer (score 2):

So the reason it wasn't working is because I didn't realize it was coded in the element to only support a few languages.

My solution was to edit/fork the prism + prism-element components.
(Note: If you edit the files inside bower_components without changing the name or directory you may lose changes upon next update)

I edited the `prism-element/prism-highlighter.html` file to include additional languages:

```
if (lang === 'js' || lang.substr(0, 2) === 'es') {
  return Prism.languages.javascript;
} else if (lang === 'css') {
  return Prism.languages.css;
} else if (lang === 'c') {
  return Prism.languages.clike;
} else if (lang === 'bash') { // Check for bash markdown
  return Prism.languages.bash;
} else if (lang === 'python') { // Check for python markdown
  return Prism.languages.python;
} else {
...
```

The `prism/gulpfile.js` to import more language components:

```
paths  = {
  componentsFile: 'components.js',
  components: ['components/**/*.js', '!components/**/*.min.js'],
  main: [
    'components/prism-core.js',
    'components/prism-markup.js',
    'components/prism-css.js',
    'components/prism-clike.js',
    'components/prism-javascript.js',
    'components/prism-bash.js', // Include bash component
    'components/prism-python.js', // Include python component
    'plugins/file-highlight/prism-file-highlight.js'
  ],
...
```

If you changed the name/path of `prism`, make sure to change the relative paths in `prism-element/prism-import.html`.

Then in the `prism` folder run `npm install` to install dependencies, and `gulp` to run `gulpfile.js` and compile to `prism/prism.js`.

Since I named my fork prism-highlighter-plus, my final code looks like this:

````
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/marked-element/marked-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/prism-element-plus/prism-highlighter-plus.html">

<dom-module id="backup-script">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      .markdown-html {
        overflow-x: auto;
      }
    </style>

    <prism-highlighter-plus></prism-highlighter-plus>

    <marked-element>
      <div class="markdown-html"></div>
      <script type="text/markdown">
        ```bash
        #!/bin/bash

        ...
        excluded_databases="Database|information_schema|performance_schema|mysql"
        databases=`mysql -u $mysql_user -p$mysql_password -Bse "SHOW DATABASES;" | egrep -v $excluded_databases`

        for db in $databases; do
          mysqldump -u $mysql_user -p$mysql_password --databases $db > $mysql_output/$today/$db.sql
        done
        ...
      </script>
    </marked-element>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'backup-script'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
````